# SAS Char and Numeric types in a Numeric colum

Tags: sas

I hope you can help with the below problem.

I have a dataset with a Char column with for example '000000036', 'C', 'M' etc. I want to convert this column to a Numeric column with the examples above displayed as 36, C, M etc.

Thanks

Tope

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and what didn't work. Google should find plenty of examples of char to numeric conversions. If all of the alpha values  are one character, representing them with special missing values may be an option.

Comment: I have tried using the input function and also multiplying the variable by * 1, but both eliminates the char inputs (i.e. C and M) from the newly created variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS numeric values can have special missing values, which are referenced in code as .A .B .C etc, but when printed they display as A B C.  If your variable only has one character long alpha values, this may be the easiest way to maintain the characters.  You can use the MISSING statement to tell SAS which characters represent special missing values.

```
data have;
  input cvar $3.;
  cards;
036
C
M
;

missing C M;

data want;
  set have;
  nvar=input(cvar,3.);
  put cvar= nvar=;
run;

missing; *restore default;
```

If your data has longer character strings, you would need to use a different approach for the conversion (perhaps a custom informat), but I would still consider using special missing values, assuming you have no more than 27 unique character values in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric columns can only store numbers or missing values.  It is possible to display numbers as character, using a format, but that is not relevant here.

@Quentin is correct in that you can use special missing values to display your letters, although as he points out, these are restricted to single letters only.  SAS usually stores missing numeric values as a period (.), but you can also use the letters A-Z and the underscore to represent special missing values, these are actually stored as .A, .B, .C,----> ._ .

If you use the `missing` statement in a data step with all the alphabet letters, then it will automatically assign and display the relevant letter as the special missing value.  If any character values are more than one letter then it won't be able to convert or display that value.

```
data have;
input char_col $15.;
datalines;
000000036
C
M
;
run;

data want;
set have;
missing a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z;
num_col=input(char_col,best12.);
run;
```